# RDLC child dataset displaying only 1 data

Tags: sql, report, rdlc

I have 3 datasets, one which is the parent and two child datasets, the thing is the child has multiple records in it and it keeps returning only the first value, I am looking for a way to display all

the expression for the textbox is the following:

```
    =First(Fields!Test1.Value, "Test_dataset")
```

I'm not quite sure if i am doing the right thing here.

Comment: First observation: You are using "First" function - which will always return only one value. However, your question doesn't have enough details about the report design to be able to help you in a meaningful way.

Comment: i noticed the first function thing, but even when I remove it, it doesn't work

Comment: Text box is not going to repeat itself and it's not bound to data source. You need to use list or table to achieve that, but again, you need to provide more details in your question and at least go over some rdlc tutorial before asking this kind of question.

Comment: Yes I have been going through some but still haven't found out, when I use table it doesn't filter the data so I have to add parameters however i don't know how to linked those parameters to the id of my main dataset. so that I can have data that is relevant to the parent dataset